# Multiplying Cardinal Numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, set-theory

I was just reading a proof of the dimension theorem in Steven Roman's Advanced Linear Algebra. In addressing the cases of infinite bases, Roman proceeds to show that if $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{C}$ are bases of a space $V$, then $|\mathcal{B}|\leq |\mathcal{C}|$, working up to an application of the BSC-Theorem. Anyway, he uses the string

$$|\mathcal{B}|\leq\aleph_0|\mathcal{C}|=|\mathcal{C}|.$$

Sorry if it's an elementary question, but why does the equality follow? Here $\mathcal{C}$ is any infinite basis. Is it definition? I tried looking up multiplication of ordinals, but didn't find anything useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

No, it's not a definition. A theorem of Tarski says that if $A$ is an infinite set, then $|A| = |A \times A|$. An acessible proof of this can be found in Hungerford's "Algebra". So using it and the Schröder-Bernstein theorem, it's easy to prove that if $A$ is an infinite set and $B$ is a non-empty set such that $|B| \le |A|$, then $|A||B| = |A|$.

Comment: I'll try to get my hands on a copy of that book, thanks!

Comment: @MSE: It's on page 20.

Comment: Actually Tarski's theorem is that $|A|=|A\times A|$ implies the axiom of choice; it was Zermelo who proved that $|A|=|A\times A|$ for infinite sets (assuming, of course, the axiom of choice).

Answer (score 6):

By hypothesis $\mathcal C$ is infinite so $\aleph_0|\mathcal{C}|= \max(\aleph_0,|\mathcal C|)  = |\mathcal{C}|$ by basic [cardinal arithmetic.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number)

Comment: Thanks, I see what I needed now that you pointed out what to look for.

Answer (score 3):

Seeing how the essential question was answered, I want to stress something else in your post which needs to be pointed out:

It is true that cardinals (namely, [Aleph numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleph_number)) are usually treated as ordinals, however the multiplications and addition of cardinals and ordinals are very different, and most of all - exponentiation is different as well.

For ordinals $\alpha$ and $\beta$ we define the sum to be:

- $\alpha + 0 = \alpha$
- $\alpha + (\beta + 1) = (\alpha + \beta) + 1$ (where $+1$ is the successor ordinal)
- $\alpha + \beta$ for a limit ordinal $\beta$ is the limit of $\alpha+\gamma$ for $\gamma<\beta$

One can notice that it is usually non-commutative as $2+\omega = \sup\{2+n\colon n<\omega\} = \omega \neq \omega+2$.

The [ordinal multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic#Multiplication) is defined in a similar way, as well [exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic#Exponentiation). (Namely a simple rule for zero, and successor and a limit for limits) and an interesting result is that $\omega^\omega$ is **countable** when dealing with ordinal exponentiation.

In contrast, if $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are cardinals then $\lambda + \mu = \mu + \lambda = \lambda \cdot \mu = \mu \cdot \lambda = \max \{\lambda, \mu\}$, and the exponentiation is defined as $\lambda^\mu = |\{f | f\colon\mu\to\lambda\}|$ - that is the cardinality of the collection of functions from $\mu$ into $\lambda$.
For further information and definitions you can see [this wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number#Cardinal_arithmetic)

So once you were dealing with the cardinality of the basis you were looking for cardinal arithmetics and not ordinal arithmetics. Which are two different things.