# In P. Cohen's models (or others) may we have $\neg\mathsf{AC}+\mathsf{CH}$? May we have $\neg \mathsf{AC} + \neg \mathsf{CH}$?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice, forcing

I know we have the consistency of $\mathsf{ZF} + \mathsf{AC} + \mathsf{GCH}$, $\mathsf{ZF} + \neg \mathsf{AC}$, and $\mathsf{ZF} + \mathsf{AC} + \neg \mathsf{GCH}$.

What about $\mathsf{ZF} + \neg \mathsf{AC}  +  \mathsf{CH}$ and $\mathsf{ZF} + \neg\mathsf{AC} + \neg\mathsf{CH}$?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please clarify your question by at least spelling out what all these abbreviations mean.

Comment: Are you just asking whether the Continuum Hypothesis is independent of $\mathsf{ZF}{+}{\neg}\mathsf{AC}$?

Comment: [Here](http://mathoverflow.net/q/150373/767) is a related question on mathoverflow. [Joel David Hamkins' answer](http://mathoverflow.net/a/150376/767) seems to imply that ZF + $\lnot$AC + CH is consistent.

Comment: @Arthur: And if $\sf AC$ is independent of $\sf ZF+CH$, as it seems.

Comment: I second Asaf's remark that it is important to define $\mathsf{CH}$ carefully in the absence of $\mathsf{AC}$.  It is possible to have a surjection from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\omega_2$ but no injection from $\omega_1$ to $\mathbb{R}$, for example (this follows from the Axiom of Determinacy.)

Comment: @Trevor: Maybe it's also worth pointing out that in models of $\sf ZF+AD$ you also get the perfect set property for $\Bbb R$ so there are no intermediate cardinals, despite the fact that $\Bbb R$ can be mapped onto many different cardinals.

Answer (score 2):

There's really nothing much to it.

We can easily use symmetric forcing the axiom of choice to fail only above rank $\omega+\omega$. Then if $\sf CH$ was true in the ground model, it will be true while $\sf AC$ is false; and if $\sf CH$ was false in the ground model, it will be false in the symmetric extension.

Do note, however, that $\sf CH$ has several formulations which end up non-equivalent when the axiom of choice fails. See [How to formulate continuum hypothesis without the axiom of choice?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/404807/how-to-formulate-continuum-hypothesis-without-the-axiom-of-choice) for more details. And while we're handing out links, [The Continuum Hypothesis & The Axiom of Choice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/472957/the-continuum-hypothesis-the-axiom-of-choice) seems relevant as well.