# Direct proofs $ 2m < 2^m $ and $ 2^m \not\le m^2 $ for infinite cardinals

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

I am after the simplest and most direct proofs available that $2\mathfrak{m} < 2^\mathfrak{m} $ *and* $ 2^\mathfrak{m} \not\le \mathfrak{m}^2 $ for infinite $ \mathfrak{m} $ *given* GCH but not AC.

This is in connection with proving GCH implies AC in a Kelley-Morse setting, and I am after the tersest most direct proof I can get assuming Foundation and that the theory of ordinals and cardinals have already been defined and developed to some elementary level without AC.

This is a result of Specker, and there are several articles on generalisations and more powerful results. See for example [Andrés E. Caicedo](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314741/question-about-generalized-continuum-hypothesis) which almost gives me what I am looking for.

I hope to avoid a lot of lemmas and theorems around choice and well-orders and get straight to these two results. I have not been able to figure out how to do this easily, although this paper seems close [Kanamori and Pincus](http://math.bu.edu/people/aki/7.pdf)

Comment: In ZF there is more than one "version" of GCH.  One is that if $A$ is Tarski-infinite and $A\leq' B\leq' P(A)$ then $A\sim B$ or $A\sim P(A), $where $A\leq'B$ means there is an injection $f:A\to B,$ and $A\sim B$ means there is a bijection $g:A\to B,$ and $P(A)$ is the power-set of $A. $ Another is that if $K$ is an infinite cardinal ordinal then $P(K)\sim K^+.$

Comment: @Daniel: They turn out to be all equivalent, as they all imply the axiom of choice... What's Tarski-infinite, though?

Comment: @AsafKaragila. Tarski-infinite is "not Tarski-finite".

Comment: @Daniel: Yes. I can imagine that would be the definition. Let's go one step further. What is "Tarski-finite"?

Comment: Probably means Dedekind-finite?

Comment: @Mark: Probably not, probably just means "finite".