# A question about infinite sets and Cantor's Power Set theorem

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals, axiom-of-choice

Let $\operatorname{Card}(X)$ denote the cardinal number of the set $X$. The standard proof of Cantor's Power Set theorem stating that "$\operatorname{Card}(X) < \operatorname{Card}(2^X)$" is simple, straightforward and does not use the Axiom of Choice.

If $X$ is any infinite set, is there a simple, straightforward proof of the statement "$2\operatorname{Card}(X) < \operatorname{Card}(2^X)$" which does not use the Axiom of Choice?

Comment: I seem to have messed up entering the question. Most of what I wrote somehow got deleted.. Is there any way to get it back?

Comment: 2card(X) = card(X) < card(2^X) if card(X) is transfinite.

Comment: @wythagoras: Without the axiom of choice this is not necessarily true. See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/393196/the-relationship-of-frak-mm-m-to-ac), for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple. $2\cdot\operatorname{Card}(X)$ is the cardinality of $X\times\{0,1\}$.

Now consider the following injection: $$\langle x,i\rangle\mapsto\begin{cases}\{x\} & i=0\\ X\setminus\{x\} & i=1\end{cases}$$

This gives us $\leq$; whereas in the other direction, if $\operatorname{Card}(2^X)=2\cdot\operatorname{Card}(X)$, we have that $\operatorname{Card}(2^X)\leq \operatorname{Card}(X)^2$ (because it is always true that $2\cdot\operatorname{Card}(X)\leq\operatorname{Card}(X)^2$.

This is impossible, though, since the latter is false for any $X$ with at least five elements, let alone an infinite set.

To see a proof of the latter without choice, see Jech *The Axiom of Choice*, Lemma 11.10 (p. 160 of the Dover reprint).

Comment: @ Asaf: This is the kind of proof I was looking for. Thanks also for bringing back what was deleted from my6 post.