# partition of an infinite set with copies

Tags: set-theory

Here is my current concern.

Say that a set $E$ has the half-property when there exist sets $F$ and $G$ such that $E$ is the disjoint union of $F$ and $G$, $F$ and $G$ being isomorphic. Trivially, no finite set has the half property, whereas (trivially as well) any countable set or the set of real numbers has the half-property.

It seems to me that any infinite set has the half-property, but I feel that this could be related to some axiomatic system (involving the choice? I don't know). If $E$ is (up to isomorphism) a power set, then take $E'$ such that $E=\mathcal P(E')$, a in $E'$ and take $F$ as the subsets containing a and $G$ as the subsets without a; can this be helpful to solve the problem?

Thanks in advance for your thoughts!

Comment: Not sure I am following,  If $E=\{1,2\},F=\{1\},G=\{2\}$ isn't $E=F\coprod G$?

Comment: Oops sorry, I wrote something stupid, moreover I finally found the real good question answered somewhere else... thanks for your time!

Comment: Also related, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/393196/

Comment: thanks for redirecting me to the question properly written and sorry for not finding it before posting :(

Comment: Also, "half-property" is a pretty odd name for "even".